# share Account usage data to another snowflake instance

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to share some of the data from **snowflake instance 1 snowflake.account_usage** to snowflake instance 2

**can we do it with materialized views ?**
like create a materialized view on top of snowflake.account_usage.table1 in snowflake instance 1 and then data share it to snowflake instance 2?

What could be other possiblities to get this data from snowflake instance 1 to snowflake instance 2 other than using copy command?

Comment: Assuming both accounts are part of the same Org, have you looked at the SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE views to see if they contain the data you want?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake database is a shared database available to each account. Shared databases and all the objects in the database cannot be re-shared with other accounts.

Please review the below documentation for more information:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-share-consumers?utm_source=snowscope&utm_medium=serp&utm_term=shared+database+limitation#general-limitations-for-shared-databases

As a workaround, you could create a regular database from the snowflake shared database in account1 and then share the regular database to other snowflake account account2. If the source and target are in different region then you can use database replication.